# file_exists() does not find files outside of web root/script dir

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to figure out why my php script is not able to find files outside of the web-root. It is part of a larger application but this seems to be the minimum for reproducing my issue.

I'm running php version 8.1.27 and nginx version 1.24.0.

This is the script in `/var/www/testing/index.php`:

```php
# /var/www/testing/index.php
<?php
        $devPath = '/dev/dri/renderD128';
        if (!file_exists($devPath)) {
            echo "File does not exist!";
        } elseif (!is_readable($devPath)) {
            echo "File is not readable!";
        } else {
            echo "All good!";
        }
        clearstatcache();
?>
```

will display `File does not exist!`

But if I create:

```
# touch /var/www/testing/testing
# chown http:http /var/www/testing/testing
```

and change `devPath` to `/var/www/testing/testing`, the script displays `All good!`.

I was thinking that maybe the `/dev/` files are special in this context for some reason so I created:

```
# touch /tmp/testing
# chown http:http /tmp/testing
```

and changed `devPath` to `/tmp/testing`. But I still get `File does not exist!`.

my `php-fpm.conf` looks like this:

```
[global]
error_log = log/php-fpm.error.log

[testing]

user = http

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 2

listen = /run/php-fpm-legacy/testing.sock
listen.owner = http
listen.group = http
listen.mode = 0660

access.log = /var/lib/$pool/php-fpm-access.log

access.format = "%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t %R: \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f %{milli}d %{kilo}M %C%%"

slowlog = /var/lib/$pool/php-fpm-slow.log

env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/lib/$pool/php-fpm-error.log

php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

and my `php-fpm.ini` is empty.

I serve the file using nginx, I suspect that config is ok as I can navigate to the server and see the results, but in either case, the config looks like this:

```
user http;
worker_processes auto;

error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    root /var/www;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    types_hash_bucket_size 128;

    server {
         listen       80;
         server_name  123.123.0.123;
         root         /var/www/testing;

         access_log /var/log/nginx/testing.access.log;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/testing.error.log error;
         index index.html index.htm index.php;

         location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         }

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-legacy/testing.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 444;
    }
}
```

To the best of my abilities I have verified that:

- the file exists:
- the `http` user is in the render group
- it is the `http` user running the php process
- the correct `php-fpm.conf` is used

```
# ls -lah /dev/dri/renderD128
crw-rw-rw- 1 root render 226, 128 Feb  2 22:49 /dev/dri/renderD128
# groups http
render redis http
# ps aux | grep php | grep testing
http      116949  0.0  0.0  79256 10036 ?        S    18:24   0:00 php-fpm: pool testing
# ps aux | grep php | grep master
root      116935  0.0  0.0  79404 19676 ?        Ss   18:24   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-legacy/php-fpm.conf)
```

I've also tried to add an `open_basedir` directive to see if I can get a hint or if maybe it was set somewhere else, but it results in the following error:

```
Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/dev/dri/renderD128) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/testing:/dev/dri/renderD128) in /var/www/testing/index.php on line 3
```

Somewhat expected, but it seems weird that it complains when the path is among the allowed ones.

I've also tried listing the files in the directory by changing the `index.php` script to:

```php
<?php
        $devPath = '/dev/dri/';
        print_r(scandir($devPath));
?>
```

which gives me the following output:

```
Warning: scandir(/dev/dri/): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory in /var/www/testing/index.php on line 3

Warning: scandir(): (errno 13): Permission denied in /var/www/testing/index.php on line 3
```

However listing at a lower level, so `/dev/` gives me some output:

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => char [3] => core [4] => fd [5] => full [6] => hugepages [7] => log [8] => mqueue [9] => null [10] => ptmx [11] => pts [12] => random [13] => shm [14] => stderr [15] => stdin [16] => stdout [17] => tty [18] => urandom [19] => zero )
```

But the `/dev/dri` directory is nowhere to be seen in that output.

I'm all out of ideas on where to look next. What could be the cause of php not being able to find the file? Is there some default (or non default) setting that would prevent this?

EDIT: I've tried to make sure that the files should be readable and listable by the `http` user. The `/dev` and `/dev/dri` directories have `755` permissions; the `/dev/dri/renderD128` file has `666` permissions and is owned by a group that the `http` user belongs to; the `/tmp` directory has `777` permissions; and the `/tmp/testing` file has `644` permissions and is owned by the `http` user.

Comment: You may also check [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1073790/nginx-error-open-basedir) of the stackexchange network and see whether it gives you some insights

Comment: The /dev folder is a "devices" folder, which are system items, some of them mounted...i.e drives. I would assume that /dev/dri is such a device. On the command line check the output of: cat /etc/mtab. That will show the mount points of any devices, and the folder they are mounted to. If /dev/dri is a device, it will be mounted somewhere, and that will be the path you should be accessing.

Comment: well, the `renderD128` device is an interface to the GPU and used for HW acceleration when transcoding video (for example with `ffmpeg`), and I suppose other similar tasks. It is not mounted in mtab, when used with `ffmpeg` you would pass the device path. It doesn't seem like it is the `renderD128` file itself, as the script also is unable to find the `/tmp/testing` file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the php installation, on my system, defaults to setting the `PrivateDevices=yes` setting in the systemd service definition of `php-fpm`.

[The systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html) says that the setting:

> If true, sets up a new /dev/ mount for the executed processes and only adds API pseudo devices such as /dev/null, /dev/zero or /dev/random (as well as the pseudo TTY subsystem) to it, but no physical devices such as /dev/sda, system memory /dev/mem, system ports /dev/port and others. This is useful to turn off physical device access by the executed process. Defaults to false.

This basically mean that the process will not see any of the global `/dev` devices, this is reasonable and a safety feature. But it also means that `/dev/dri/renderD128` will be hidden from the process, thus the reason for my error.

Additionally the systemd service definition sets `PrivateTmp=yes`, which does the same thing but for `/tmp` so me testing the process's access by creating something in `/tmp` put me on the wrong track. I tried to create the external file in `/home/http` instead and the script could access it fine.

We don't want to remove these settings as they are a security and safety feature, preventing the process from accessing other processes' data and system files/devices it shouldn't. However, we can create exceptions by adding:

```
BindPaths=/dev/dri/renderD128
DeviceAllow=/dev/dri/renderD128 rw
```

to the `[Service]` section of php-fpm's systemd service file. This will allow the process to access that specific file even if devices in general are blocked.

I could also add the `open_basedir` directive back without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that PHP must have "r" access rights on the file `renderD128` and "x" access rights on all its parent folders, e.g. `/dev` and `/dev/dri`.

The 'x' ('execute' if on files but 'list contents' if on directories)  access right is needed for the `file_exists()` operation because it allows PHP to traverse and access directories in the given path. Without execute permission on a directory in the path, PHP won't be able to reach and check the existence of the specified file or directory.

---

Update: I missed the "open_basedir restriction in effect." in your answer. There is a setting in PHP that restricts opened files to listed folders. You apparently have that set. For more details see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: good point, and thanks for your answer. The `/dev` and `/dev/dri` directories both have 755 permissions, so I believe anyone should be able to list them. The `renderD128` file has 666 permissions (and is owned by the same group as the reading user). The `/tmp` director has 777 and the `/tmp/testing` file has 644 and is owned by the reading user. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the answer :/

Comment: Sorry, I missed the message in your output "open_basedir restriction in effect." - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir - you need to adjust that php.ini setting.